# "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream - NGINX

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

Olá,
estou tentando executar meu site do Wordpress na Host que possui está configuração:

- Ubuntu LTS 16.04, Nginx, Apache, MySQL, PHP, Webmin

Ao tentar entrar na página inicial, o erro que é exibido no arquivo de **error log**, é este abaixo:

> 2018/05/03 02:35:22 [error] 3372#3372: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 187.103.234.71, server: meusite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "meusite.com"

Alguma ideia do que possa ser?
Comecei a me aventurar agora na criação do meu próprio servidor, então os erros começaram a aparecer e preciso de ajuda para entender a raiz e tentar resolver.

Obrigada!

Comment: Se você tiver conhecimento em inglês (eu sou ruimzin) tem uma resposta aqui: https://serverfault.com/q/517190

Comment: @Don'tPanic Vou dar uma olhada!

Answer (score -1):

O seu problema é esta na configuração fastcgi.
No Webmin >>> Vá para VirtualMin >>> Selecione o Dominio >>>
Services >> Server configuration >> Website Options

Lá deve ter mais de uma opção, alem do selecionado CGI.
Selecione outra opção e Salve.

O SITE NAO IRA FUNCIONAR (MAS VERIFIQUE, TALVEZ SEJA O CASO DE TROCAR SUA CONFIGURAÇÃO)
CASO SEU SITE NÃO VOLTE...
Faça o mesmo caminho acima e volte para CGI como estava.
Assim o seu site vai reconfigurar o SOCKET do CGI.

---

### **NGINX & APACHE é Servidor Web e Proxy Reverso**

Isto é os dois só pode ser utilizado se você configurar em portas diferentes.

Por exemplo:

APACHE= PORTA:8080
NGINX= PORTA:80
Caso use cache como Varsish, verifique as configurações de portas

Contudo utilizando os dois é possivel.
Configurar o Nginx como um Servidor Web e Proxy Reverso Apache.

Comment: Na verdade, dá pra rodar o Apache como webserver e o NGINX como proxy, como é feito no VESTACP, por exemplo.